# Why I should define a JLabel before a addActionListener?

Tags: java, swing

I have one JLabel and one JButton into JFrame. I write code for actionPerformed  event of JButton like following:

```
btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            lblA.setText("Hello"); // error here
        }
    });
final JLabel lblA = new JLabel("");
```

but i get following error:

```
lblA cannot be resolved
```

however if I placed define of JLabel before addActionListener like following my problem solved:

```
final JLabel lblA = new JLabel("");
btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            lblA.setText("Hello"); // error here
        }
    });
```

Also if i define a variable after it, i get similar error and i should define variable before it.

But in C# i can define a variable after one method and use variable into method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Local` variables are depends on position. If you define variable outside of constructor or method, than position will not matter. Try with following declaration:

```
public class X extends JFrame{

    X(){
          JButton btnOK=new JButton("OK");

        btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            lblA.setText("Hello"); // error here
        }
    });
     //        final JLabel lblA = new JLabel("");
    }

    JLabel lblA = new JLabel("");// Try to declare here outside of constructor.

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new X();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you declare the variable `lblA`, how do you plan to use it(its undefined). The compiler won't know about such a variable unless its declared.

That is why, when you place that code above the `listener`, you can use that `lblA` within it(since `lblA` is now known). Thus, you can only use a variable after its declaration. If you try to use it before that, it will be undefined and will throw compilation errors(that the variable can't be resolved).

**E.g:-**

```
System.out.println(test); // Print what? I don't know who or what test is.
String test = "I'm a String"; // Test variable declaration.
```

On reversing the order,

```
String test = "I'm a String"; // Test variable declaration.
System.out.println(test); // I know test. I'll print it.
```

Comment: OP's question is regarding the declaration position. Not whether or not he or she should declare...

Answer (score 1):

`variables` are defined in the order that they are declared. The variable is undefined before being declared

Comment: @Reimeus No all variables, but local variables maintain order.

Comment: Yes but if you notice Masud's answer you can see that lblA is declared after the method. Declarations like that will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are acessing a reference, the `lblA`, before its declaration. It's like use something taht not exists, so, the second way is the correct form to do it.